# How to list sound files in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, alarm, avplayer

In my app I imported 4 sound files. Now I want to list all the sound files in a View. When the user clicks any one of the sound, it needs to be selected and played as like in the Alarms app (choosing the sound for alarm). The difference here is I am getting the sound from my project. I have searched in SO and Google but I couldn't find a solution exactly for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "In my app i imported 4 sound files" means that the files are in your app bundle (and also assuming that the extension of the files is MP3 - you can change it to whatever extensions they actually have):

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSFileManager *mgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

NSArray *allFiles = [mgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePat error:NULL];
for (NSString *fileName in allFiles)
{
    if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mp3"])
    {
        NSString *fullFilePath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        // fullFilePath now contains the path to your MP3 file
        DoSomethingWithFile(fullFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes.. you are correct i will test this and let you know.. thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks thats working perfectly fine.. I can get all the mp3 files..+1 and i tried to play the audio files using this code `NSURL *file = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shake_sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:&error];
      
     audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];` but it returns an error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)` any idea thanks

Comment: @Vinoth you're creating the URL wrong. `NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullFilePath]`

Comment: @ahmad no need to yell. Probably he isn't yet permitted. I hope he'll accpt it.

Comment: sorry for the delay.. I just tried your NSURL code.. Its working perfectly fine.. Many thanks

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry for this simple question. while playing one of the sound file in ViewDidLoad it keep on playing the sound and also post the error(edited in question) plese check it

Comment: @Vinoth seems like an internal framework error, file a bug to Apple and ignore it

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks but the AudioPlayer plays the sound with out getting stop

Comment: @Vinoth `[audioPlayer stop];` :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15053/discussion-between-vinoth-and-h2co3)